# Concept about $\binom{ \infty}k$

Tags: number-theory, combinations, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

concept about *function* $\binom{ \infty}k$
For 
$ k \in \mathbb{N}$

The idea of ​​this function is derived from my power sum formula

[link for my power sum formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265732/647719)

Formula is as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m}=\sum_{b=1}^{m+1} \binom{n}b\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$$

This formula helps to derive $\binom{ \infty}k$ function and to calculate it's value.  we know the negative values of zeta function.if

$$ \zeta(-m)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m}$$

So can we construct it as
 $$\zeta(-m)=\sum_{b=1}^{m+1} \binom{\infty}b\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$$
Then we can calculate, if we substitute value $\zeta (0)=-1/2$ then$\binom{\infty}1=-1/2$

Again we can calculate next value using or substituting previous values of $\binom{\infty}k$.

Other values of $\binom{\infty}k$are

$$\binom{\infty}2=5/12$$
$$\binom{\infty}3=-3/8$$
$$\binom{\infty}4=251/720$$
$$...$$
And so on.

**Application**

*Definition*

Let's us define a sequence as :

$$a=(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...)$$

Difference between two term is as follows

$$\triangle^{0}a_{n}=a_{n}$$
$$\triangle^{1}a_{n}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}$$
More generally
$$\triangle^{m}a_{n}=\triangle^{m-1}a_{n+1}-\triangle^{m-1}a_{n}$$
If there exist some $m$ for $\triangle^{m}a_{n}=0$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Then $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}=\sum_{b=1}^{m+1} \binom{n}b\triangle^{b-1}a_1$$

now if $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ put values $\binom{\infty}b$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k}=\sum_{b=1}^{m+1} \binom{\infty}b\triangle^{b-1}a_1$$

And Get the result

**Example**

To calculate 
$1+3+5+...+(2n-1)+...=1/3$

**Question**

> > Q1- how this *function* $\binom{\infty}k$ impact to understanding  and  analysis of mathematics?
> >
> > Q2- can we derive it's definition/algorithm to calculate  *function* $\binom{\infty}k$ for $k\in\mathbb{C}$  values by analysis in some field , i mean what is generalization for *function* $\binom{\infty}k$?
> >
> > Q3-Is it have some interesting properties?

Thank you very much for your suggestions comments and answer.

Comment: Is this a similar try to make something nonsensical meaningful as the "equation" $$1+2+3+4+\cdots =-1/12$$ ?

Comment: The equation $$\zeta(-m)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m}$$ is not true at all. The RHS diverges whereas the LHS is a well defined constant value.

Comment: Ok, may be i need to study more...

Comment: I wouldn't say it's necessarily illegal. Simply *defining* $\binom{\infty}{n}$ by an expression like
$$
\zeta(-m)=\sum\binom{\infty}{n}\sum ...
$$
is not strictly speaking wrong. The better question would be, do these numbers have some interesting properties? Is there any deeper way in which they are related to the standard binomial coefficients? That the answers here are in the affirmative is not at all obvious.

Comment: Pruthviraj,   You might want to check out "Three ways to sum a divergent series"    https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/09/06/sum-a-divergent-series/

Comment: I always say: $\infty$ is a direction, not a number

Comment: It seems legal, it has a well-defined unique value, but I wouldn´t denote it as $\binom{ \infty}k$.

Comment: I agree Peter Foreman. And for me, the concept given in this question makes no sense. If we arrive at equations like the example in this question it should be obvious that the concept is not actually valid.

Comment: To justify $1+2+3+4+\cdots =-1/12$ because of the zeta-function is like saying "I can buy a plane" by just ignoring not to have enough money.

Comment: Do you understand my answer ? You are doing a weird/unnatural summation method for polynomials

Comment: @reuns Yes I understand but don't know which type of algebraic rules behind it,to generalize . Yes it's weird but it satisfied us on some conditions. may be Q1&Q3 are not sharp but it interesting and important,

Answer (score -1):

- There is a unique polynomial $P_m(x)$ such that $P_m(0) = 0$ and $P_m(x)-P_m(x-1)= x^m$ so $P_m(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^m$ and you are setting $$P_m(\infty) = \zeta(-m)$$
- For any polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(0) = 0$ then $f(x)-f(x-1)$ is a polynomial $$f(x)-f(x-1) = \sum_{j=0}^d c_j x^j$$

  You are setting $$f(\infty) = \sum_{j=0}^d c_j \zeta(-j)$$
- With $g_l(x) = {x \choose l}$ then $$g_l(x)-g_l(x-1) =\sum_{j=0}^{l-1} b_{l,j} x^j$$
  $${\infty \choose l} =\sum_{j=0}^{l-1} b_{l,j} \zeta(-j)$$
- From $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1} = \frac{1+(-1)^{N+1}}{2}$ we have that $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ is entire and $$\eta(-j) = \lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^j x^n$$
  Let $$T (\sum_{j=0}^d c_j x^j)(x) = \sum_{j=0}^d \frac{c_j}{1-2^{1+j}} x^j$$
  you are setting $$f(\infty) = \lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}x^n T(f(x)-f(x-1))(n) $$
  The problem is that operator $T$ which makes it unobvious how to generalize your summation method to any sequences, not only polynomials.