# show that $n\Upsilon_{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ iff $n$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, bernoulli-numbers

The [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) $B_n$. where all numbers $B_n$ are zero with odd index $n>1$. first values are given by $B_{0} = 1$ ,  $B_{1} = -1/2$, $B_{2} = 1/6$,  $B_{3} = -1/30$.

Agoh conjecture: let $n$ be a positive integer with $n \ge 2$, then

$$nB_{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{n}\iff n\text{ is prime} $$

The idea of ​​$\Upsilon$ number comes from [my power sum formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3265732/647719) and negative values of zeta function

**Definition**  let $m$ be a non-negative integer
 $$\zeta(-m)=(-1)^{m}\frac{B_{m+1}}{m+1}=\sum_{b=1}^{m+1} \Upsilon_b\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$$

so we can calculate values of $\Upsilon_b$ , if we substitute value $\zeta (0)=-1/2$ gives $\Upsilon_1=-1/2$.

Again we can calculate next value using or substituting previous values of $\Upsilon_b$.

first values are given by 
$$\begin{align*}
\Upsilon_1&=-\frac{ 1}{2},\\
\Upsilon_2&=\frac{ 5}{12},\\
\Upsilon_3&=-\frac{ 3}{8},\\
\Upsilon_4&=\frac{ 251}{720},\\
\Upsilon_5&=-\frac{ 95}{288},\\
\Upsilon_6&=\frac{ 19087}{60480},\\
\Upsilon_7&=-\frac {5257}{17280}.
\end{align*}$$

> > **hypothesis:** let $n$ be a positive integer with $n \ge 2$, then
> >
> > $$n\Upsilon_{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{n} \iff n\text{ is prime} $$
> >
> > Else show that hypothesis is equivalence to agoh's conjectures
> >
> > Else 
> >     show that if n is prime then $n\Upsilon_{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{n} $
>
> **Steven Clark had verified conjecture $n\Upsilon_{n-1} \equiv -1 \pmod{n}\iff n\in \mathbb{P}$ for $2 \leq n \leq 500 $**

More simply

Let [$D_{m,b}=\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3321413/647719)

So $D_{m,m+1}=m!$

$$\Upsilon_{m+1}=\frac{(-1)^{m}B_{m+1}-(m+1)(\Upsilon_1 D_{m,1}+\Upsilon_2 D_{m,2}+\cdots+\Upsilon_m D_{m,m})}{(m+1)!}$$

[Please see my post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347233/149083)

Comment: Are you familiar with Giuga's conjecture? It's in the same territory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh–Giuga_conjecture

Comment: @Gerry_Myerson yes I am giuga's and agoh's conjectures are equivalence

Comment: So, what evidence do you have for your hypothesis?

Comment: @Gerry_Myerson Based on given $\Upsilon_n$ values I have assumed my hypothesis is true but  I am working on a program for further observation

Comment: I believe $\Upsilon_6=\frac{19087}{60480}$ and $\Upsilon_7=-\frac{5257}{17280}$.

Comment: @StevenClark Up till what values have you checked ?

Comment: I deleted one of my earlier comments after I found an error in my code. Assuming no more errors in my code, I've now verified your conjecture $n\,\Upsilon_{n-1}\equiv -1\,(mod\ n)\,\iff\,n\in \mathbb{P}$ for $2\le n\le 500$. My interest in this question is partially motivated by my conjectured formulas for $\zeta(-j)$ in my question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262873.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347233/show-that-n-upsilon-n-1-equiv-1-pmodn-iff-n-is-prime

Answer (score 1):

This post is not intended as an answer but rather a way to share results and code as originally requested by the OP.

Assuming no errors in my code, I have now verified the conjecture $n\,\Upsilon_{n-1}\equiv -1\,(mod\ n)\,\iff\,n\in \mathbb{P}$ for $2\le n\le 1000$.

I attached an image of my Mathematica code to provide others the opportunity to verify correctness of my code and use it to explore the conjecture for a larger range of $n$ values if so desired.

[image: Screenshot of code]