# what is formula for $\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$ and Real Roots Polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Definition

let $b$ and $m$ are non negative integers with $b\ge 1$

$$D_{m,b}=\sum_{i=0}^{b-1} (-1)^{i}(b-i)^{m}\binom{b-1}i$$

I observed

$$D_{m,m+1}=m!$$

$$D_{m,m}=(m+1)!/2$$

$$D_{m,m-1}= (m+1)!(3m-2)/24$$

$$D_{m,m-2}= (m+1)!(m-1)(m-2)/48$$

$$\dots$$

> > what is general formula for $D_{m,m-k}$ ?

Let define $F_k=D_{m,m-k}=0$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Example

$F_1 = 3m-2 = 0  \implies m = 2/3$

$F_2 = (m-1)(m-2) = 0  \implies m = 2,1$

> > Prove or disprove
> >
> > $F_k \implies m \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \forall k$

Comment: Have you tried searching [OEIS](http://oeis.org)?

Comment: The form of the sum is very similar to (but not exactly) Stirling's numbers of the second kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: @JairTaylor yes I tried and get this reference of unpublished notes:https://oeis.org/A000629/a000629.pdf . but not explain general formula

Comment: I cannot even parse the final claim $F_k\implies \forall m\in \Bbb R$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I mean all roots of $F_k $ belongs to real number not complex.

Comment: As you can see in the last part of my answer below, $~D_{m,m-5}=0~$ answers your second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is

> $$D_{m,b}=(b-1)!\,S(m+1,b)$$

where $~S(m,n)~$ are the $\,$ *Stirling numbers of the second kind* (exist several different notations).

It comes e.g. from $~\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}D_{m,k+1} = e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx}(e^x \phi_m(x))~$ where $~\phi_n(x)~$ is the [Bell polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html).

This means, that you want to know if all roots of $~S(x+1,x-k)=0~$ are real.

We can develope the polynomial

> $$S(x,x-k) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}c_{k,j}\,{\binom x {\,2k-j~}} ~~ , ~~~~ k\in\mathbb{N}$$

of degree $~2k~$ with the following recursion:

$c_{1,0}:=1 ~~ , ~~ c_{k,j}:=0~$ for $~j\notin\{0,1,…,k-1\} ~~ ,$

$c_{k+1,j} = (k+1-j)\,c_{k,j-1} + (2k+1-j)\,c_{k,j}$

Some more values:

$\displaystyle c_{k,0}=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!} ~ , ~~ c_{k,1}=\frac{k-1}{3}c_{k,0} ~ , ~~ c_{k,2}=\frac{(k-2)(2k-3)}{6(2k-1)}c_{k,1}$

$\displaystyle c_{k,k-1}=1 ~ , ~~ c_{k,k-2}=2^{k+1}-k-3 ~ , ~~ c_{k,k-3} = \frac{1}{2}(3^{k+2}+k^2+7k+13) – (k+5)2^{k+1}$

---

*Note 1:* $~~S(x+1,x-k)=S((x+1),(x+1)-(k+1))$

*Note 2:* $\displaystyle~\binom {x} {k+1}~$ devides $~S(x,x-k)\hspace{2cm}$ (polynomial division)

$\hspace{1.6cm}$ It remains to solve $\displaystyle~\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}c_{k,j}{\binom {2k-j} {k+1}}^{-1} {\binom {x-k-1} {k-1-j}} =0~$ .

$\underline{\text{Test}}~$ :

For $~k:=3~$ we get:

$\displaystyle~\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2}c_{3,j}{\binom {6-j} {4}}^{-1} {\binom {x-4} {2-j}} = \frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{2}= 0 ~~~$ => $~~~$ Only real solution values.

For $~k:=4~\,(2<x<5)~$ and $~k:=5~\,(2<x<6)~$ we have also only real solution values.

For $~k:=6~\,(2<x<7)~$ we have three real and *two complex* solution values.

Or with other words:

$\hspace{1cm} D_{m,m-5}=0~$ has (all in all) ten real (possibly multiple) and two complex solution values.

And this *negates* the second question.

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful

Comment: @Pruthviraj : You are welcome, it was a pleasure. ;)

Comment: @Pruthviraj : The answer for your first question is the formula and the answer for the second question is "No". Something else you like to know or is it o.k. ?

Comment: Yup it is o.k., honestly it's difficult for  me to go through your answer since my exams are going on but after my exams I will definitely look after it. But I give green tick to your answer.

Comment: Please ask if there is a problem of understanding. For the determination of the formula, I have only given a recipe, but it's not a problem to perform it. ;) (good luck with your exams!)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually one of the basic identities for the [Stirling N. of 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) is
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  n \cr 
  m \cr}  \right\}\quad  = {1 \over {m!}}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)j^{\,n} \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - j} }  = {1 \over {m!}}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( {m - j} \right)^{\,n} \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} } 
$$
which confirms the formula already provided by @user90369
$$
D_{\,m,\,\,b}  = \left( {b - 1} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  b \cr}  \right\}
$$

Now you ask to find the factorization of
$$
D_{\,m,\,\,m - \left( {q - 1} \right)}  = \left( {m - q} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  m + 1 - q \cr}  \right\}\quad \left| {\;0 \le q \le m} \right.
$$

To this aim,  a possible approach is offered by the very interesting identity 
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x \cr 
  x - n \cr}  \right\} = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( \matrix{
  x + n - 1 - k \cr 
  2n \cr}  \right)} \quad \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;x \in C \hfill \cr 
  \,0 \le {\rm integer }n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which, through the binomial, can be extended also to real and complex $x$.
(re to the renowned *"Concrete Mathematics"* - pag. 270).
Here the double angle brackets denote the [Eulerian N, 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Eulerian_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

So we have
$$
D_{\,m,\,\,m - \left( {q - 1} \right)}  = \left( {m - q} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  m + 1 - q \cr}  \right\} = \left( {m - q} \right)!\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{
  q \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( \matrix{
  m + q - k \cr 
  2q \cr}  \right)} \quad \left| {\;0 \le q \le m} \right.
$$

The first values of $q$ give:
$$
\eqalign{
    & \left( {m - 0} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   m + 1 \cr}  \right\}
 = 1\left( \matrix{  m \cr   0 \cr}  \right)m!
 = m!\quad \left| {\;0 \le m} \right.  \cr 
  & \left( {m - 1} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   m \cr}  \right\}
 = \left( {m - 1} \right)!\left( {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  1 \cr  0 \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle
 \left( \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   2 \cr}  \right) + \left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  1 \cr   1 \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( \matrix{  m \cr   2 \cr}  \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m - 1} \right)!\left( \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   2 \cr}  \right) = \left( {m + 1} \right)!/2\quad \left| {\;1 \le m} \right.  \cr 
  & \left( {m - 2} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   m - 1 \cr}  \right\}
  = \left( {m - 2} \right)!\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q}
 {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  2 \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( \matrix{  m + 2 - k \cr   4 \cr}  \right)}
  = \left( \matrix{  m + 2 \cr   4 \cr}  \right) + 2\left( \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   4 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m - 2} \right)!{{\left( {m + 2} \right)\left( {m + 1} \right)\left( m \right)\left( {m - 1} \right)
 + 2\left( {m + 1} \right)\left( m \right)\left( {m - 1} \right)\left( {m - 2} \right)} \over {4!}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m - 2} \right)!\left( {m + 1} \right)\left( m \right)\left( {m - 1} \right){{\left( {m + 2} \right) + 2\left( {m - 2} \right)} \over {4!}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m + 1} \right)!{{3m - 2} \over {4!}}\quad \left| {\;2 \le m} \right. \cr} 
$$
as you already found.

To generalize it, let's convert the Binomial into [Falling and Rising Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$
\eqalign{
  & D_{\,m,\,\,m - \left( {q - 1} \right)}  = \left( {m - q} \right)!\left\{ \matrix{  m + 1 \cr   m + 1 - q \cr}  \right\}\quad \left| {\;0 \le q \le m} \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {m - q} \right)!\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle
  \left( \matrix{  m + q - k \cr   2q \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {m - q} \right)!} \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q}
 {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( {m + q - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2q\,} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {{1^{\,\overline {\,m - q\,} } } \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q}
 {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( {m - q + 1 - k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,2q\,} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle 
{{\Gamma \left( {m - q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {m + q + 1 - k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 1 \right)\Gamma \left( {m - q + 1 - k} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle
 \left( {m - q} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,m + q - k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left\{ {\matrix{   {m!} & {0 = q}  \cr 
   {{{\left( {m + 1} \right)!} \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q - 1} {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle
 \left( {m - q} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } \left( {m + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,q - 1 - k} } } } & {1 \le q \le m}  \cr 
 } } \right. \cr} 
$$
the last coming from the fact that the diagonal of the Eulerian Numbers is null, except when both indices are $0$.

In conclusion we can extend $D_{\,m,\,\,m - \left( {q - 1} \right)} $ to complex $m$ as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & D_{\,z,\,\,z - \left( {q - 1} \right)}  = {{\Gamma \left( {z + 2} \right)} \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q}
 {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( {z - q} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } \left( {z + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,q - 1 - k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {2q} \right)!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,q}
 {\Gamma \left( {z + 1 + q - k} \right)\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( {z - q} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }
 \quad \left| \matrix{  \;z \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr   \;0 \le q \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
 }$$
where:
 - the case $q=0$ is emcompassed, being
$$
\eqalign{
  & q = 0\quad  \to \,D_{\,z,\,\,z + 1}  = \quad \Gamma \left( {z + 2} \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,0}
 {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( z \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } \left( {z + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - 1 - k} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \quad \Gamma \left( {z + 2} \right)\left( {z + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - 1} }  = {{\Gamma \left( {z + 2} \right)} \over {z + 1}} = \Gamma \left( {z + 1} \right) \cr} 
$$
 - the second line comes from considering that the Gamma function does not have zeros, 
yet it has simple poles which annihilate those in the Rising Factorial.

Thus,  concerning the zeros, let's consider first the sum in the first line, alone.
For $1 \le q$, it is a linear combination, with positive integral coefficients,  of $q-1$ polynomials 
each of degree $q-1$ and with integral roots in the interval $\left[ { - q, - 2} \right] \cup \left[ {2,q} \right]$.
None of the roots is common to all the polynomials.
Analyzing the first small values of $q$, it looks that the combination succeeds and preserve for odd $q$ two integral roots 
at $q-2, \; q-1$, and that in any case all the roots have positive real part, so none of them coincides with the poles of Gamma.
So there are $q-1$ roots, some real and some complex.
This might be due to the fact that the Eulerian N. increase at increasing the lower index, but difficult to demonstrate.

Comment: Woe... Thank you so much, Does this show $\exists k$ s.t. $F_k \implies \exists m \in \mathbb{C} $?

Comment: @Pruthviraj: I recasted the conclusions, to better address the argument of the zeros.