# Representing sum of power in different way.

Tags: number-theory

**Definition** . For $m ≥ 0$, the $m$th power-sum denominator is the smallest positive
integer $d_m$ such that $d_m · (1^m + 2^m + · · · + n^m) $is a polynomial in $n$ with integer
coefficients.
The first few values of $d_m$ (see , [Sequence A064538](https://oeis.org/A064538)) are
$d_m = 1, 2, 6, 4, 30, 12, 42, 24, 90, 20, 66, 24, 2730, 420, 90, 48, 510, . . . .$

Define
$$\begin{split} S_m(n)&= 1^m+2^m+...+n^m \\  &= \frac{1}{d_m}\sum_{l=1}^{m+1} b_l n^{l} \end{split}$$

> Can it be shown that
>
> Let $n=d_mt+r$ where $t\ge0,r\ge 0$ then $S_m(n)$ may represent as
>
> $$\begin{split} S_m(n)&= \sum_{l=1}^{m+1}(x_lt+y_l)n^{l-1}\end{split}$$
>
> With $x_l$ and $ y_l$ are integers.

Example

Let $m=2$ gives $S_2(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\to d_2=6$

let $r=2\to n=6t+2$

And $S_2(n)=(2t+1)n^2+(t)n^1+(3t+1)n^0$

Here $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$ are $2,1,3,1,0,1$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem 1**: Given $b_1,b_2,...,b_m,b_{m+1}$ finite integers. Denominator $d$ is smallest positive integer for $b_l$ integer coefficient. consider $n=dt+r$ then

$$\sum_{0<l\le m+1}\binom{n}l a_l= \frac{1}d\sum_{0<l\le m+1}b_ln^{l}=\sum_{0<l\le m+1}(x_lt+y_l)n^{l-1}$$

With $x_u$ and $y_u$ integers.

**Proof**: Denote $$\sum_{0<l\le m+1} b_l(h+r)^{l}=\sum_{0<l\le m+1} c_l h^{l}$$

The numbers $c_l$ are still integers, and we have, denoting $dt+r=n$,
$$
\frac1d\sum_{0<l\le m+1} b_l(dt+r)^{l}\\ =\frac1d\sum_{0<l\le m+1} c_l (dt)^l\\ =\sum_{0<l\le m+1} c_l t\cdot (dt)^{l-1}\\
=\sum_{0<l\le m+1} c_l t\cdot (n-r)^{l-1}\\ =
\sum_{0<l\le m+1\\ 0\leqslant j\leqslant l-1} c_l {l-1\choose j}(-r)^{l-1-j}n^jt,
\\ =\sum_{0<l\le m+1} (x_lt+y_l)n^{l-1}$$

[Source link (MO post)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362137/149083)

---

**Formula**

Let $n$ and $m$ are the integers with $n\geq 1$ and $m\geq 0$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{m}=\sum_{l=1}^{m+1} \binom{n}l\sum_{i=0}^{l-1} (-1)^{i}(l-i)^{m}\binom{l-1}i$$

[Proof link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3265862/647719)

Consider $$a_{l,m}=\sum_{i=0}^{l-1} (-1)^{i}(l-i)^{m}\binom{l-1}i$$

By theorem 1 $$S_m(n)=\sum_{l=1}^{m+1} \binom{n}la_{l,m}=\sum_{l=1}^{m+1}(x_lt+y_l)n^{l-1}$$