# A Special Observation on Prime Numbers and $\pi (n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

**Update**

Please check recently [posted on M.O](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347796/149083)

---

$\eth(n)$ is a little algorithm I made, which may appear to be quite complex, so I will start with an example middle of the post. Questions are at the end of the post.

> > *Definition*
> >
> > Let $W$ be the function ,  defined as $W(a,b)=r$
> >
> > Let's given $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a>1$
> >
> > Take $m$ to be the integer s.t. $a^{m+1} \ge b > a^{m}$, i.e. $m = \lceil \log{b}/\log{a} \rceil - 1$.
> >
> > Arrange as: $$a^{m+1} - b$$ $$ = r_{l} a^l + r_{l-1} a^{l-1}+... + r_1 a^1 + r_0 a^0 $$
> >     $$=(r_{l} r_{l-1} ... r_{1} r_{0})_{a}$$
> >
> > Where $r=\sum_{i=0}^{l}r_{i}$

●We can prove easily

$W(a,b)=r$ iff $b+r\equiv 1($ mod $a-1)$

●*Note* $W(a,0)=$ not define

Now here $n \in \mathbb{N}$

◆ $S$ is a function defined as

$$S(a,n)=\sum_{i=1}^{a}i^{n}$$

Let's $p$ is **prime**
and $p+1=z$

◆ $\eth$ is a function defined as

$$\eth (n) = \sum_{W(z,W(z,S(z,2n)))\ne z}1$$

> > ●  **I strongly observed**
> >
> > If $ z>2n+2$ Then $W(z,W(z,S(z,2n)))=z$
> >
> > Hence I conclude
> >
> > •$$\eth(n)\leq \pi (2n+1)$$
> >
> > •$$\eth(n) \approx \pi (n)$$
> >
> > •$$|\eth(n) - \pi (n)|\leq 2$$

**Observation table**

$$\begin{array}{c | c | c |c | }  n & \eth(n) & \pi(n) \\ \hline
1 & 2  & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 3 & 1 \\    \hline 
3 & 3 & 2 \\ \hline
5 &4& 3 \\ \hline
9 &4& 4 \\ \hline
10 &5& 4 \\ \hline
50 &15& 15 \\ \hline
100 &26& 25 \\ \hline
200 &44& 46 \\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

**Example**

we want to find $W(6,W(6,S(6,2)))$

First calculate $S(6,2)=1^{2}+2^{2}+...+6^{2}=91$

$\implies W(6,W(6,91))$

Here for calculate $W(6,91)$

$ 6^{3}-91 = 125 = (325)_{6}$

$\implies r = \sum r_{i} = 3+2+5 =10$

$hence W(6,91) = 10$

Again to calculate $W(6,W(6,91))=W(6,10)$

$6^{2}-10 =26 = (42)_{6}$

$\implies r=\sum r_{i} = 4+2 =6$

Hence $W(6,W(6,S(6,2)))=6$

**Table For $W(t,W(t,S(t,2)))$ which helps to calculate $\eth(1)$.**

$$\begin{array}{c | c | c |c | }  t & W(t,S(t,2)) & W(t,W(t,S(t,2))) \\ \hline
2 & 2  & 0 \\ \hline
3^{*} & 3 & 0 \\    \hline 
4^{*} & 4 & 0 \\ \hline
5 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline
6^{*} & 10 & 6 \\ \hline
7 &5 & 2 \\ \hline
8^{*} &14& 8 \\ \hline
9 &12& 13 \\ \hline
10 &12& 16 \\ \hline
11 & 15  & 16 \\ \hline
12^{*} & 22 & 12 \\    \hline 
13 & 10 & 3 \\ \hline
14^{*} & 26 & 14 \\ \hline
15 & 21 & 22 \\ \hline
16 &20 & 26 \\ \hline
17 &24& 25 \\ \hline
18^{*} &34& 18 \\ \hline
19 &15& 4 \\ \hline
20^{*} &38& 20 \\ \hline
21 &30& 31 \\ \hline
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

$t^{*} = z $

From table $W(t,W(t,S(t,2)))$  we can calculate $\eth(1)$ by counting $z$ such that $W(z,W(z,S(z,2)))\ne z$. we can observe it's only happens when $z=3$ and $4$ hence $\eth(1)= 2 $

◆ $\chi$ is function defined as

$$\chi(n)=\sum_{p \nmid S(p,2n)}1=\sum_{p-1|2n}1$$

And $ n \in \mathbb{N}$

[Proof for $\chi(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3252005/647719)

$\implies \eth (n)\geq \chi(n)$

> > **Question**
> >
> > - What is formula for $\eth(n)$?
> > - Can we prove above observation ?

You can check by using below program

'''python

```
n1= 2
o = 1
while n1 < 300:
    m = 2
    print("\n n1=",n1)
    #print("m=",m)

    num=n1
    sum_num = 0

    for i in range(1, num+1): 
        sum_num += i**(m)
    n2 = (sum_num)
    #print("$n1^2m=",n2)

    rem_array = []
    while n2 != 1:
        mod = n2%n1
        if mod != 0:
          rem = n1-mod
          n2 = n2 + rem
          rem_array.append(round(rem))
          n2 = n2/n1
        else:
            n2 = n2/n1
            rem_array.append(0)         
    #print(rem_array[::-1],sum(rem_array))
    #print(sum(rem_array))

    n2 = sum(rem_array)
    rem_array = []
    while n2 != 1:
        mod = n2%n1
        if mod != 0:
          rem = n1-mod
          n2 = n2 + rem
          rem_array.append(round(rem))
          n2 = n2/n1
        else:
            n2 = n2/n1
            rem_array.append(0)
    #print(rem_array)
    #print(rem_array[::-1],sum(rem_array))
    if(n1 == sum(rem_array)):
        print("W(",n1,",W(",n1,",S(",n1,",m)))=",n1)
    #else:
        #print("not ok")                

    n1 += o
```

'''

Comment: $\Lambda$ and $\Omega$ both have standard meanings in Analytic Number Theory, so they are not good choices for names of your functions.

Comment: @Gerry_Myerson Yes you are right now it's changed

Comment: Take a look at the [other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime-numbers) to see how you need to improve yours (simplify, shorter, motivated)

Comment: Please check post on M.O https://mathoverflow.net/q/347796/149083