# Show that, If $a-1\mid S(a-1,2m)$ and $a-1>2m+1$ then $(f(a,2m))_a\in X_a$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Define $X_a$ be the set as, namely$\{ x=(\ \underbrace{ 1\ 1\cdots\ 1\ 1}_{\text{$n$ terms}}\ \ 0 \ \ \underbrace{ \alpha_t\ \alpha_{t-1} \cdots \alpha_1 \ \alpha_0}_{\text{$k$ terms, k=t+1}})_a \mid\ n,k\ge 0\ and \ a-1 \ge \alpha_j\ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge 1 \ for \ t\ge j \ge 1 \} $

and $x\notin \{1,11,111,...\}$

*Note*: $x$ have at most only one '0' digit.

*Example* for set$X_{10}$

$x= \begin{align}  5 \\ 932 \\ 1108552 \\ 1111097322 \\110111 \\ 11103221 \\ 11110 \\ \vdots
\end{align}$

For positive integers $n,m$, let
$$S(n,m)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^m$$
and for positive integers $m,b$, with $b>1$, let $D(b,m)$ be the sum of the base-$b$ digits of $m$.

Define $f(a,k)=\frac{D(a,a^{k+1}-S(a,k))}{a-1}$

> **Problem**
>
> Given $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 4}$ and $m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$
>
> Show that, If $a-1\mid S(a-1,2m)$ and $a-1>2m+1$ then $(f(a,2m))_a\in X_a$

$(f(a,2m))_a$ is representing the value of $f(a,2m)$ in base $a$.

*this question is equivalent to my unsolved question [check](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3398042/647719)*

---

proof for $m=1$

suppose $a$ is a positive integer such that $a \mid S(a,2)$, and let $b=a+1$.

Identically, we have
$$
S(n,2)
=
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
=
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&a \mid S(a,2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a{\;|}\left(
\frac{a(a+1)(2a+1)}{6}
\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&6 \mid \left((a+1)(2a+1)\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&6 \mid \left(b(2b-1)\right)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&6 \mid b\;\;\text{or}\;\;\Bigl(2 \mid b\;\;\text{and}\;\;3 \mid (2b-1)\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
If $6 \mid b$, then
\begin{align*}
S(b,2)&=\frac{b(b+1)(2b+1)}{6}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^3}{3}+\frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{b}{6}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{3}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^2 
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
\left({\small{\frac{b}{6}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(b,S(b,2))
=
\left({\small{\frac{b}{3}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{6}}}\right)
=
b
$$
If $2 \mid b$ and $3 \mid (2b-1)$, then $b\equiv 2 \pmod3$, so
\begin{align*}
S(b,2)&=\frac{b(b+1)(2b+1)}{6}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{b^3}{3}+\frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{b}{6}\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{b+1}{3}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^2 
+
\left({\small{\frac{b-2}{6}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^1
+ 
\left({\small{\frac{b}{2}}}\right)\!{\cdot}\,b^0
\end{align*}
hence
$$
D(b,S(b,2))
=
\left({\small{\frac{b+1}{3}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b-2}{6}}}\right)
+
\left({\small{\frac{b}{6}}}\right)
=
b.
$$
Thus, for all subcases, we have $D(b,S(b,2))=b$

$\implies D(b,b^3-S(b,2))$

$= 3a+1-D(b,S(b,2))= 2a$

and $2\in X_b$

and also note $a\in \{6t\pm 1\}$ then $a|S(a,2)$ and $a>3$.

Comment: Now posted on M.O. https://mathoverflow.net/q/347742/149083

Comment: Solution for above problem posted on M.O.  https://mathoverflow.net/a/347766/149083